# Creating product/Service in Quickbooks Online in an Invoice line item

Tags: c#, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I'm trying to create the service/product type in the invoice line item. It returns an error saying bad request, is my ItemRef phrased correctly. My service/product is created in qbo already, its called Subscription Fee, it's the 3rd in the dropdown list.

```
line.AnyIntuitObject = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.SalesItemLineDetail()
                            {
                                ItemRef = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.ReferenceType()
                                {
                                    Value = "3",
                                    type = "Item",
                                    name = "Subscription Fee"
                                },
                                ItemElementName = Intuit.Ipp.Data.ItemChoiceType.UnitPrice,
                                AnyIntuitObject = (decimal)item.Rate, // Line item rate
                                Qty = (decimal)item.Quantity,
                                QtySpecified = true,
                                ServiceDate = DateTime.Now.Date,
                                ServiceDateSpecified = true,
                                TaxCodeRef = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.ReferenceType()
                                {
                                    Value = taxCode0ZR.Id,
                                    type = Enum.GetName(typeof(Intuit.Ipp.Data.objectNameEnumType), Intuit.Ipp.Data.objectNameEnumType.TaxRate),
                                    name = taxCode0ZR.Name
                                },
                            };
```

What am i creating wrongly please help.

Comment: Enable logging, and post the full XML/JSON request that you're sending to Intuit so that we can see what you're doing. If possible, post the full XML/JSON response too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create an Item within an invoice or rather any entity within an entity.
QBO v3 does not supports creating entities on the fly.
You first need to do a create Item.
Get the Id of that Item and refer it in your Invoice.

Also, enable request/response log to get the details of the errors in log files-
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0150_ipp_.net_devkit_3.0/0002_configuration/override_configuration

Comment: The item is created in qbo already. Do you mean i'll need to load the items from qbo and send it in with the invoice?

Comment: yes, you should load the item based on docnumber or some filter or load all items and then refer it in your invoice.

Comment: Whoever has downmarked my answer, please note that Joshua has mentioned in the first line-I'm trying to create the service/product type in the invoice line item. This is incorrect. He later added details that this item is already existing.

Comment: Joshua, please add you request/response log files, so that we can identify the issue.

Comment: I managed to pull the information down from qbo as you've mentioned. And it worked! thanks for your help nimisha~ :D